# How to use Rscript with readr to get data from aws s3

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some R code with readr package that works well on a local computer - I use list.files to find files with  a specific extension and then use readr to operate on those files found.

My question: I want to do something similar with files in AWS S3 and I am looking for some pointers on how to use my current R code to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

What I want:
Given AWS folder/file structure like this
 - /folder1/subfolder1/quant.sf
 - /folder1/subfolder2/quant.sf
 - /folder1/subfolder3/quant.sf
and so on where every subfolder has the same file 'quant.sf', I would like to get a data frame which has the S3 paths and I want to use the R code shown below to operate on all the quant.sf files.

Below, I am showing R code that works currently with data on a Linux machine.

```
get_quants <- function(path1, ...) {
    additionalPath = list(...)

    suppressMessages(library(tximport))
    suppressMessages(library(readr))

    salmon_filepaths=file.path(path=path1,list.files(path1,recursive=TRUE, pattern="quant.sf"))

    samples = data.frame(samples = gsub(".*?quant/salmon_(.*?)/quant.sf", "\\1", salmon_filepaths) )
    row.names(samples)=samples[,1]
    names(salmon_filepaths)=samples$samples


    # IF no tx2Gene available, we will only get isoform level counts
    salmon_tx_data = tximport(salmon_filepaths, type="salmon", txOut = TRUE)


    ## Get transcript count summarization
    write.csv(as.data.frame(salmon_tx_data$counts), file = "tx_NumReads.csv")
    ## Get TPM
    write.csv(as.data.frame(salmon_tx_data$abundance), file  =  "tx_TPM_Abundance.csv")


    if(length(additionalPath > 0)) {

        tx2geneFile = additionalPath[[1]]
        my_tx2gene=read.csv(tx2geneFile,sep = "\t",stringsAsFactors = F, header=F)
        salmon_tx2gene_data = tximport(salmon_filepaths, type="salmon", txOut = FALSE, tx2gene=my_tx2gene)

        ## Get Gene count summarization
        write.csv(as.data.frame(salmon_tx2gene_data$counts), file = "tx2gene_NumReads.csv")
        ## Get TPM
        write.csv(as.data.frame(salmon_tx2gene_data$abundance),  file  =  "tx2gene_TPM_Abundance.csv")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it easiest to use the aws.s3 R package for this. In this case what you would do is use the `s3read_using()` and `s3write_using()` functions to save to and from S3. Like this:

```
library(aws.s3)
my_tx2gene=s3read_using(FUN=read.csv, object="[path_in_s3_to_file]",sep = "\t",stringsAsFactors = F, header=F)
```

It basically is a wrapper around whatever function you want to use for file input/output. Works great with read_json, saveRDS, or anything else!

Comment: Hi Jacuqeline, Thanks for your answer.. Is it possible to get a listing of all the directories (S3 buckets in this case) that have the file I am trying to find using regular R code..

Let us say  I have  

/data/path/folder1/quant.sf
/data/path/folder2/quant.sf
/data/path/folder3/quant.sf

my R code will get these and then operate on this.

In a similar manner, if I have my S3 structure as:

/bucket/folder1/quant.sf
/bucket/folder2/quant.sf
/bucket/folder/3/quant.sf

I need a way to get this structure and then use tximport and readr with the above.

Comment: Yup! The `aws.s3::get_bucket()` function lists all of the files with a given key. So you can do `aws.s3::get_bucket(key="/bucket/folder1/", max=Inf)` to get everything in that folder. You can then use lapply or purrr::map to apply a function to each file in there (like say, s3read_using)

Comment: @user10101904 have you considered reading the package documentation? A lot of information there...